# Invalid cast exception in main activity.cs of xamarin forms android app

Tags: xamarin

Unable to convert instance of type `Android.Support.V7.Widget.AppCompatTextView` to type `Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar` getting exception after installing BottomNavigationBar plugin for Android to implement bottom tabs in Xamarin forms

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the app in the device & deployed again.It solved..